# PHP and SQL - Trying to change user login data, does nothing

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, input

I'm trying to create a form that lets an administrator change a user's password. I used this to create the forms on the page. The first  allows deletion and works fine, the second should be sending the new password from the form to a function that sends to the post function I'll post below it.

```
echo <<<_END
  <pre>
username $row[0]
role $row[2]
 </pre>
  <form action="admin2.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="$row[0]">
  <input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD"></form>

  <pre>password <input type="text" name = "password"></pre>
  <form action="admin2.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="change" value="yes">
  <input type="hidden" name="username" value="$row[0]">
  <input type="submit" value="CHANGE PASSWORD">

_END;
```

And the if statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['change']) && isset($_POST['username']) && 
isset($_POST['password']))
  {
$username   = get_post($connection, 'username');
$password   = get_post($connection, 'password');
$query  = "UPDATE users  SET password='$password' WHERE username='$username'";
$result = $connection->query($query);

if (!$result) echo "UPDATE failed: $query<br>" .
  $connection->error . "<br><br>";
}
```

The page loads but when I press the button there isn't any change on the backend. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Ok, having made the changes linked to above, it does change the password but only when it's the last entry in the table. Otherwise it just deletes the entry on the table below it.

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['username']))
{
$username   = get_post($connection, 'username');
$query  = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$result = $connection->query($query);

if (!$result) echo "DELETE failed: $query<br>" .
  $connection->error . "<br><br>";
}
```

Comment: Perhaps something may not be set in `$_POST`..

Comment: Can you see any errors in the logs?

Comment: I don't see any errors. I'm not sure what else I would need to set in `$_POST`. I made an edit I'll add above, thought it'd be correct but now it deletes the entry below it instead of changing the password

Comment: I added `method="post"` to the form declaration. Then it started doing the problem I described above

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is , put the password input in the second form tag.like this (the the button name to edit.) :

```
<form action="admin2.php" method="POST">
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    ......
    <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />
</form>
```

The admin2.php cannot read the password post because the form not send the password in the post request.

The change the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST["edit"]))
{
    if(isset($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"])){
      $username   = get_post($connection, 'username');
      $password   = get_post($connection, 'password');
      $query  = "UPDATE users  SET password='$password' WHERE username='$username'";
      $result = $connection->query($query);

      if (!$result) echo "UPDATE failed: $query<br>" .
         $connection->error . "<br><br>";
      }
}
```

Your problem is, you run two form in one php script, so you need to differ which form refer to which PHP code block. If you put 2 form run on one PHP script, with the same names (include the button), then the server will run from the first PHP script that contain the names.

Comment: That just has my new problem, my delete function uses post as well and for some reason the Change Password is deleting the entry below it on the table.

Comment: You need to seperate the php code. If isset delete then delete code run. If iset edit, edit code run. You password input is out of the form tags, so the form will not send the password value to the php.

Comment: Moving the password didn't fix it, it's still deleting. I'll post my delete code above, but it should be separated from what I can tell.

Comment: because your first PHP is reading from the username and password. The delete PHP, put if(isset($_POST["delete"])). In you delete html form, change the button name to "delete".

Comment: I'm confused. The whole thing is in PHP, I have the if isset statement for delete already, and delete never gets called when I press the password button so it should be impossible for it to get called.

Comment: The input with name "delete" is no use when you put the name delete on the button.

Comment: ? I can't figure out what I should change. I don't have the word delete in the second form.

Comment: The first form, your submit button, add an attribute name="delete", in your second form put name="edit". In the edit PHP code block, you dont need isset($_POST["username"]), you only need isset($_POST["edit"]). Its the same like in the delete code block, just put isset($_POST["delete"]) only.

Comment: Ok, that finally worked. Thank you so much, sorry I was obtuse about this for a while.

Comment: Ok, no never mind. It only worked once, after that I can't delete or change a password.